# how i can read multiple folders in java and should return every folder accordingly?

Tags: java

```
File file = new File(java.getProperty("db.filenew"));
File[] files = file.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // for (File file1 : files) {

    if (files[i].isDirectory()) 
       files[i].getCanonicalPath();

    if (files[i].isFile()) 
       files[i].getPath();
    files[i].getName().endsWith(".xml");
```

here i am reading the files from.properites.i have used the follwing snippet to read every file from that particular folder but its returning the folders only not files.so please help me.

```
    public void readfile(File file) {
        file.getPath();
        File fileattribute = null;
        if (fileattribute.isFile()) {
            this.readfile(fileattribute);
        }

    }

    public File readdirectory(File fi) throws InterruptedException,
    ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        File sub[] = fi.listFiles();

        for (File f_ar: sub) {

            if (f_ar.isDirectory()) {

                this.readdirectory(f_ar);

            }


            return fi;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your read directory method add another clause to your if statement in your for loop to check if the File is a file and then call your read file method.

```
public File readdirectory(File fi) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException     
{     
    File sub[] = fi.listFiles(); 
    for (File f_ar : sub) 
    { 
        if (f_ar.isDirectory())    
        { 
              this.readdirectory(f_ar); 
        }
        else
        {
              this.readfile(f_ar);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a class to store list of folder and file

For example :

1. Create a class for Folder

```
    class Folder
{
    private List folders = new ArrayList();
    private List files = new ArrayList();
    private String name;
    private String path;


    public List getFolders() {
        return folders;
    }

    public void setFolders(List folders) {
        this.folders = folders;
    }

    public List getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Folder(String name, String path) {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void addFolder(Folder subfolder) {
        folders.add(subfolder);

    }

    public void addFolderFile(String name, String canonicalPath) {
        files.add(new FolderFile(name, canonicalPath));

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Folder [name=" + name + ", path=" + path + "]";
    }


}
```

2. Create a class for File

   ```
   class FolderFile
   {
   private String name;
   private String path;


   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getPath() {
       return path;
   }

   public void setPath(String path) {
       this.path = path;
   }

   public FolderFile(String name, String path) {
       this.name = name;
       this.path = path;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "FolderFile [name=" + name + ", path=" + path + "]";
   }


   }
   ```
3. Create an instance of Folder Class for root folder

```
 File root = new File(java.getProperty("db.filenew"));
        Folder folder = null;
        if(root.exists())
        {
            File[] allFiles = root.listFiles();
            folder = new Folder(args[0], root.getCanonicalPath());
            readDirectory(folder, allFiles);

        }
```

5. Read directory

```
 private  void readDirectory(Folder folder, File[] allFiles) throws IOException {

        for (File file : allFiles) {
            if(file.isDirectory())
            {
                Folder subfolder = new Folder(file.getName(), file.getCanonicalPath());
                folder.addFolder(subfolder);
                readDirectory(subfolder, file.listFiles());

            }
            else
            {
                folder.addFolderFile(file.getName(),file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        }
    }
```

6. Retrive the information from Folder object

```
readFolder(folder);
```

7. Read Folder Object

private void readFolder(Folder folder) {
        System.out.println(folder.toString());
        //List of Folder
        List folders = folder.getFolders();
        System.out.println("Sub-Folder under Folder :" + folder.getPath());
        System.out.println("*******************************************");

```
    for (Folder subfolder : folders) {
        System.out.println(subfolder.toString());
        readFolder(subfolder);
    }
    //List of Files
    List<FolderFile> files = folder.getFiles();
    System.out.println("File under Folder :" + folder.getPath());
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    for (FolderFile folderFile : files) {


        System.out.println(folderFile);
    }


}
```